# Edit embed message per 1min | Discord.js V12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'd like my bot to send a message and then edit it once per minute with the following value:

```
client.users.cache.size
```

I tried the following code, but unfortunately, it did not work.

```js
const timejkdfg = new MessageEmbed().setTitle("testing").addField(":", client.users.cache.size);
message.channel.send(timejkdfg).then((msggg) => {
    const timejk1dfg = new MessageEmbed().setTitle("testing").addField(":", client.users.cache.size);
    setInterval(function () {
        msggg.edit(`${timejk1dfg}`);
    }, 60000);
});
```

Instead of showing the number of users cached, it shows "`[object Object]`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code runs every minute but it doesn't have the effect you want it to have. That is because you create the `timejk1dfg` constant outside of the `setInterval` function. That means it will only be created once and after that it is always the same, not really what you want here. The fix is pretty easy, just move `timejk1dfg` into the Interval and remove the string from your `.edit`.

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("testing").addField(":", client.users.cache.size);
message.channel.send(embed).then((msg) => {
    setInterval(function () {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("testing").addField(":", client.users.cache.size);
        msg.edit(embed);
    }, 6000);
});
```

*NOTE: I made your naming a little more conventional*

As to your problem of `client.users.cache.size` showing `[object Object]`, I couldn't replicate that. I suggest a `console.log(client.users.cache)` to see what is actually in there.